# Format function in Access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have the following query in MS Access and needs to be converted to SQL Server.  I am trying to understand what does the format function do here and what is the use of "0".

```
SELECT  Format([SumOfTotalPopulation],"0") AS Expr1 , SumOfTotalPopulation FROM
  qry_ASSET_STREAM_DS_POP_PROP ;
```

Can anyone help me understad this. The above code is present in MS Access 2003 and Im working on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: [Documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx) for the Format() function.

Comment: While browsing to understand the meaning format, I have gone through these sites. But unable to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access [`Format()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx) function behaves differently based on the data type passed into it. In this example, I'm assuming that your `SumOfTotalPopulation` field is a number, which means that the formatting will be done [as described here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-property-number-and-currency-data-types-HA001232740.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001228839) - basically, it will be formatted as an integer - no decimal point, no thousands separator.

The good news for you is that if the field in SQL Server is already defined as an integer type, you won't have to do this formatting. Otherwise, you should be doing this formatting at the presentation layer (user interface, web page, report, etc.) and not in the query itself.

Access teaches a lot of bad habits. Rather than translate what you have in Access one-for-one, take this opportunity to update things to be done "the SQL Server way" wherever possible.

Comment: Access teaches a lot of bad habits? I don't think that is the case. I think people may get that impression because Access is the most accessible(lol) database software to newbies, who are teaching themselves. Anyways, this isn't really the point so I'm going to stop rambling

Comment: Hmmm.. Since my column is of integer datatype ans not decimal, it looks like I dont need to use the Format Function. That really helps. Thank you Alroc.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `Format([SumOfTotalPopulation],"0")` just removes the decimals from the number.

In SQL Server, you could use something like `Str(sumOfTotalPopulation,12,0)`

Or you could use [`Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Comment: This would do good if the column Im using is of type decimal. Since I ahvent mentioned the type in my question. This is also one of the correct answers.